# Ubuntu 18.04 on Raspberry pi zero w?

Tags: pi-zero-w, ubuntu

I am wondering if anyone has successfully  installed and ran Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on Raspberry pi zero w??
If so, can you guide me on how you accomplished  it? I have an application in mind where I need the raspberry pi zero w and an OS like UbuntubMate 18.04.

Thanks.

Comment: *"I have an application in mind where I need the raspberry pi zero w and an OS like UbuntubMate 18.04."* -> You may want to consider this as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).  Generally speaking, any and all software that runs on a particular hardware platform using one GNU/Linux distro can be run using another -- the most significant issue is versioning (different distros having different prerogatives in this regard), but if it is an issue that is often surmounted easily enough.   Put another way, the hardware platform is the limiting factor, not the distro.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Mate website you will need a Pi2B / 3B(+) or later to run any Mate version. It does not run on the single processor (BCM2835) models

[Ubuntu MATE for the Raspberry Pi 2 and Raspberry Pi 3](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/)

Answer (score 4):

You can't.
Ubuntu Mate, or other ARM flavours of Ubuntu require an ARMv7 (or ARMv8,etc...) cpu, while the original RaspberryPi and the Zero have an ARMv6 cpu.

It's very likely that the extremely similar (they are both based on Debian, even if most of the packages will have different versions) Raspbian will be ok for what you want to build.